# MySQL trigger changes in a table

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

#### I want to log any UPDATE on any table using mysql, but within the log I want to record the 'old' value and the 'new' one.

For instance I have this table:

#### user:

```
+-------------------+
| id                |
| email             |
| password          |
| birthdate         |
+-------------------+
```

values:

1:'test@test.com':'123456':'1995-07-23'

---

And I decide to change the birthday for id=1 to '1996-07-23'

So, I would like to log into 'history' table the following:

**table_name: 'user', field_name: 'birthdate', previous_value: '1995-07-23', new_value: '1996-07-23'**

#### history table:

```
+-------------------+
| id                |
| table_name        |
| field_name        |
| previous_value    |
| new_value         |
| history_datetime  |
+-------------------+
```

Any advise to achieve that ?

Comment: There it is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_update
AFTER UPDATE ON user
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO history (obj_id, table_name, field_name, previous_value, new_value, history_datetime)
  SELECT NEW.id, 'user', 'email', OLD.email, NEW.email, NOW()
    FROM user
   WHERE IFNULL(NEW.email, '') <> IFNULL(OLD.email, '')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NEW.id, 'user', 'birthdate', OLD.birthdate, NEW.birthdate, NOW()
    FROM user
   WHERE IFNULL(NEW.birthdate,'') <> IFNULL(OLD.birthdate, '');
```

- It one-statement trigger
- It logs changes only if new value differs from old value.
- It takes care of `NULL`s.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf91b6/1)** demo

Note: `id` column in history table made auto_increment, and additional `obj_id` column has been introduced to reference an `id` of an object being logged

Comment: @MichaelBarquero Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?